# Not able to write to application insights serilog when using Azure functions with dotnet-isolated runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, serilog

I have an Azure Function app that's built using .NET 6 and uses the `dotnet-isolated` runtime. The default logger pushes logs to app insights, however, wasn't capturing custom dimensions, etc.

Based on the ticket [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/371873/ilogger-structured-loggig-with-application-insight][1], I moved to Serilog.

The `program.cs` looks something like this:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .AddJsonFile("logConfig.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
     .Build();
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TraceTelemetryConverter())
    .CreateLogger();
     services.AddLogging(logging =>
    {       
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddSerilog(logger);
    });
}).Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```

Sample of the logger used in code:

```
_logger.LogInformation("xxxxxxx with invoice number: {invoiceNumber}", invoiceNumber);
```

The `logConfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {          
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "SerilogTestApplication"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Iam able to log `customproperties`, Will post an answer in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Iam able to log traces as well as  `Custom Properties`  to `Application Insights`.

I have done few changes in the  `logConfig.json`  and  `Program.cs`  files.

I can see the custom properties for my traces as well.

**My traces:**

[image]

Thanks @[camerondwyer](https://camerondwyer.com/2020/05/26/how-to-use-application-insights-custom-properties-in-azure-monitor-log-kusto-queries/) for the code.

Followed the same code from the link which you have provided to log the Custom Properties using  `TelemetryClient`.

Remove the `MinimumLevel`from the configuration file.

**My  `logConfig.json`  file:**

```cs
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=**********;IngestionEndpoint=https://westus2-2.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westus2.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "SerilogTestApplication"
    }
  }
}
```

- In `Program.cs` file, add the below line.

```cs
 .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(Conn,new TraceTelemetryConverter())
```

**`Program.cs`  file:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters;

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .AddJsonFile("logConfig.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
     .Build();

var Conn = configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"];


var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(Conn,new TraceTelemetryConverter())
        .CreateLogger();
        services.AddLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddSerilog(logger);
        });
    }).Build();

host.Run();
```

***`Function1.cs` file***

```cs
TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
configuration.InstrumentationKey = "**********";

TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);

telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Hello World!");
Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"FirstName", "Harshitha" },
    {"LastName", "Veeramalla" },
};
telemetryClient.TrackTrace("User Details",SeverityLevel.Information, properties);
```

**`.csproj`  file:**

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
```

***Output:***
[image]

Click on the Trace.

***Custom Properties:***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An interesting thing is that you do not even need to write to applicationInsights. Just write to console with json format . After published to azure, you will see your enriched properties. 
program.cs

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()

                .ConfigureServices(s =>
                {
                    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                               .Enrich.WithProperty("MyCustomProperty1", "123456789")
                               .WriteTo.Console(new JsonFormatter())
                   .CreateLogger();
                    s.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger));
                })
           .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Function1.cs     (No need DI for _logger)

```
    public class Function1
    {
        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            Log.Information("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]